# How to get the id back to jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using jquery ajax to post a form in mvc. Once i submit the form i want to get the id which is generated at the backened to my jquery call. How can i do this with mvc 4, EF and ajax.
Below jquery to post the form

```
$('.Submit').click(function () {     
       var url = "/" + Controller + "/" + Method;

        var $form = $(this).closest('form');
        var data = $form.serialize();

        $.post(url, data).done(function () {

        });
    });
```

And the post method

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(MySampleVM samplevm)
        {
//here i write my EF logic to save data to sql table .
          }
```

The save action will generate an identity column in the table and that id i needed in my jquery.

Answer (score 3):

You could return this value as a JSON result from your controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(MySampleVM samplevm)
{
    //here i write my EF logic to save data to sql table .

    // and then return the value as a JSON object to the client
    return Json(new { result = 123 });
}
```

and finally on the client simply use this value which will be passed as parameter to your callback function:

```
$.post(url, data).done(function (res) {
    alert(res.result); // will print 123
});
```